# Conditions in panda dataframe when multiplying with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, null, multiplication

I originally had the following that works:

```
df = df.replace({np.nan: 0})
df[new_cols] = df[cols].multiply(df["abc"], axis="index")
```

But I need a more exact condition. So if any of the values in a column in [cols] are NULL, then the column in [new_cols] is also NULL, otherwise the following is performed: `df[cols]*df["abc"]` to get `df[new_cols]`

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try without replacing NaN with 0? A number multiplied by NaN returns NaN

Comment: have you tried np.where ??